# Convert from lateral view to case statements in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to place below code in **case** statement:

```
select
count (*)
from db.tab1
lateral view explode(secondary.tertiary) exp as lv
where id IN ('6','1') and array_contains (lv.ci, "1");
```

I have tried:

```
select 
  sum(
    case 
      when id IN ('6','1') 
          and array_contains ((lateral view explode(secondary.tertiary)).ci, "1") 
      then 1 
      else 0 
   end) 
from db.tab1;
```

But getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select
  count(*),
  sum(if(..., 1, 0))
from db.tab1
  lateral view explode(secondary.tertiary) exp as lv
;
```

For the provided SQL on table `tab1`, the actual logic is like:

1. Explode field `secondary.tertiary`, alias it as `lv`, which results in a temporary result set (table) `tab2`;
2. A join-like operation to concatenate `tab2`'s fields back to rows in `tab1`, resulting in another intermediate table `tab3`;
3. Select from `tab3`, upon which `where` conditions are applied.